# unit testing code that depends on website?

Tags: c#, nunit

I would like to learn how to test code that I wrote that relies on an external resource.

There is a website that I scrape data from. I then parse it and save to a strongly typed domain object.

I have unit tests that test this but because they rely on an external resource - having an internet connection that has access to the website - I can't depend on the tests being able to execute at all times.

I don't want to moq the website (there is no interface anyhow), or setup local html source text files. What I would prefer is in my nunit Setup() method to create a web server that can dish up the urls just like the external website would do. Perhaps it would redirect to localhost instead of the website.

I'm not looking for a specific solution. I instead would like guidance on best practice for handling this testing situation. Especially if there is a recommended .Net library or guidance from Microsoft.

Comment: Side notes: You already crossed out recommended approaches to *unit testing* (mock data access layer with code/files)... What you trying to implement usually not called "unit tests" but more like integration tests...

Comment: mock requires an interface driven approach. the external resource has no such thing.

Comment: My comment was strictly about naming - what you are talking about is not what most people call "unit tests". Usually "unit tests" are tests that validate isolated sub-system of the program/library without any external dependencies. The fact that name of test runner to run the test includes "unit" does not make any test "unit test"...

Comment: On "external resource has no such thing" - I've never seen information from external sites magically show up and be available to code. In regular code there are some calls (i.e. via `HttpClient`/`HttpWebRequest` or web service proxies) that bring data from external site into a program. One can replace that access layer with mocked one and remove the external resource dependency...

Comment: What you are talking about sounds like another [test double](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html), viz to provide a  fake web site which exposes the same interfaces as the real one to which you are integrating, but can be configured to exercise different state at will (e.g. data scenarios, performance scenarios, downtime, etc). However, it is probably a lot more work to implement the fake / double with a tool like `Moq` than it would be to simply mock out the web service(s) e.g. via the service contract interfaces and simulate the various external states, as Alexei recommends?